# Fix typo in bounty message?

Tags: support, bounty

I'm somewhat excited to have just started [my first bounty](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141891/configuration-to-limit-time-spent-on-formatting-output)!  Imagine my dismay to have noticed a typo in the bounty message...  Can I fix this?

<sub>To be explicit, the bounty message reads "One should be able to constrain the time spent on displaying **a** formatting output. [...]" (emphasis added), whereas is should read "displaying **and** formatting output."</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have removed and refunded your bounty.  Please recreate it using the correct wording.  Please *be careful* in the future. :-)

---

As Michael E2 remarks in the comments, if anyone else has this problem a superior way to get attention is to *flag* the post for moderator attention, using the **flag** link below the post itself.  However please exercise care when creating bounties, and if you must flag do so quickly after creating the bounty as bounties that have been active for an extended time should not be refunded.

Comment: Should a user facing a similar problem flag the question for moderator intervention, to make a request to fix the problem?

Comment: @MichaelE2 It would be better to exercise care so that this doesn't happen, but so long as the flag is raised right after starting the bounty this is OK.  We want to avoid refunding bounties that have existed for a while.

Comment: I agree about being careful. I was really thinking of flagging as an alternative to posting on Meta, and that this Q&A could point that out, if flagging is in fact a better alternative.